# using cloudant nano to return documents matching a selector

Tags: cloudant

The selector is an object that describes the where part of the query. I've tried the db.list function but it' not honoring the selector.

The database admin tool of cloudant has a Query feature, you type in a selector, fields, and sort and away it goes. My guess is it's using the `_find` as opposed to `_all_docs`. (true?)

I don't see _find in the nano code. It be easy enough to call it directly, in which case I'd like to get access to the `relax` to do the http call.

1) should the selector work on db.list?
2) I'm using typescript, how can I get set up to use the relax method for the http?

Comment: just read the doc... i know how to get to request function.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the Cloudant library instead of Nano -- Cloudant's node library is a thin wrapper around Nano, giving you access to Cloudant-specific stuff. See https://github.com/cloudant/nodejs-cloudant